# Can 3d-printing be used to print drone frames which carry around 4 kilograms?

Tags: print-quality

What about the strength parameters?
Where can I give CAD models to print them and receive them?
Please guide me.

Comment: Hi @Kisor. It's not clear what you want here. Obviously, the answer is yes (why do you think it isn't? Maybe there is a factor which you think is obvious, but isn't in your question). Online 3D printing services is something you should research yourself rather than asking in the same question (price, location being some of the most critical factors that won't make for a good Q&A experience).

Comment: to get an answer to your post, you will need to [edit] it and make it more specific. This will work even if the question gets closed in the mean time (that just prevents people from trying to answer it).

Comment: do you have a Design?!

Comment: Short answer: Yes. But you'll probably need to build your own model, and it's likely to be a complicated (read: time consuming) process to get that right.

Comment: @Trish yes, I have! But not currently well-detailed.

Comment: @SeanHoulihane Yeah but I didn't think it is impossible but whether it can be used for heavy duty and payload carrying drones. I'm currently involved in a project that attempts to solve coconut harvesting with drones to solve labor pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, no problem! But this does not depend on the production process, it depends on the design.

Not only the production process (adhesion in Z direction is usually weaker than X or Y) should be taken into account, but also the choice of material. Even carbon fibre doped filaments (nylon or PLA) exist (harder to print however, due to excessive wear of the nozzle by the carbon fibres).

You can also consider using carbon fiber tubes, and only print the connectors/mounts to connect the tubes to the engine mounts and main body mount.

---

*Basically, your question is not specific enough and boils down to a "How do I design a drone frame" or "What are the main design issues for designing a drone frame", which should be asked in an other forum. Once you have a design you could change your question and ask for specifics regarding printing the parts using FDM (e.g. orientation, positioning, materials, etc.).*

Comment: Thanks:) I have considered using carbon fibre tubes but I do not know of it's fabrication processes, motor mounting fixtures and like that..